# Syntactic Tests for Reduced Relative Clauses

Tags: syntactic-analysis, reduced-relative-clauses

In a sentence such as

*Lionel Messi, 34, now plays for PSG*

a reduced relative clause can be readily seen, and I can put back what has been omitted:

*Lionel Messi, who is 34, plays for PSG*

But in something such as

*I end up doing all the work, with him being absent so frequently*

if I "complete" what I see as a reduced relative clause, I create:

*I end up doing all the work, with him who is being absent so frequently*

which sounds convoluted.

It occurred to me that what I'm doing is entirely based on an assumption or a gut feeling, that there is a "reduced relative clause" in each sentence. I mean, just because I changed things to *with him who is being absent,* is that enough to call this a "reduced relative clause"?

More to the point, Is there a reliable syntactic test to determine that an -ing word (such as "being" in th example above) is the result of a "reduced relative clause"?

Comment: I don't think that's a relative clause construction, reduced or not.

Comment: @John Lawler. Is it that relative clause reduction just doesn't work with "being"? Maybe the relative clause needs to be non-restrictive (_Mary, sitting across the table, winked at me ~ Mary, who was sitting across the table, winked at me_) but it still sounds odd with "being:" _Mary, being upset with me, didn't call me ~ Mary, who was being upset with me, didn't call me_. I'm just trying to figure out if there is an underlying rule at work. Thank you.

Comment: You're conflating the function of modifier/supplement with the category of relative clause. In your example "Lionel Messi, 34, now plays for PSG" the commas mark the noun phrase "34" as a supplement. Supplements are loosely attached elements set off by intonation (and usually punctuation) presenting supplementary non-integrated content. Sure, you can recast it as "Lionel Messi, who is 34, now plays for PSG", where "who is 34" is clearly a relative clause, but "34" in your first example is a supplementary NP, not some kind of relative clause.

Comment: You asked about syntactic tests for so-called 'reduced' relative clauses. The impossibility of such expressions containing a relative phrase means that they are not some kind of relative clause at all, but other kinds of phrase or clause functioning as modifier or supplement.